# Could not push logs to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. read timeout reached

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to set up EFK (elasticsearch, fluentd, kibana) on kubernetes cluster, so i used the following controller and service yaml files:

## fluentd-es.yaml

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/saltbase/salt/fluentd-es/fluentd-es.yaml

## es-controller.yaml, es-service.yaml, kibana-controller.yaml and kibana-service.yaml

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch

after running them, i had the following log output and kibana dashboard was unable to show me logs and charts (keep loading for ever like next image).

[image]

## fluentd log snapshot:

[image]
[image]

## elasticsearch log snapshot:

[image]

## kibana log snapshot

[image]

Comment: Please read up on how to post a question on Stackoverflow and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. ES connection is gettng time out after retrying.So make sure you are defining right es config in fluentd.conf.
2. Also this is giving- BufferQueueLimitError which comes when your queue is filled due to connection time out. If you are expecting to fix this you should define:

   buffered memory and 

     buffer_type memory
     buffer_chunk_limit **m
     buffer_queue_limit **
     flush_interval ***s
     disable_retry_limit false
     retry_wait **s

refer-
https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/buffer-plugin-overview#secondary-output

Answer (score -4):

The logs are pretty much telling you .... there's a connection problem to Elasticsearch.

Comment: But i tried to make some curl request from inside fluentd to ES and it works fine !